# How to track that the user has walked 30 meters?

Tags: ios, gps, location, coordinates, tracking

Well, I'm developing an iOS app, and at some point I need to track that the user has walked for at least 30 meters. The ideal case is to check whether he walked around a small rectangular shape (3m wide, 10m long).

How do I check that? I was trying to do it via GPS but it seems to be a not very good solution as the accuracy is to low for that. Any other ideas?

Comment: a 3x10 box has a perimeter of 26m, not 30...

Comment: It might help if you restate your goals and constraints. As is I think the answer is "you can't"; sensors on the device can give you an accurate measure of time and a much less precise measure of acceleration and position. Maybe you can construct a heuristic from those which gives you some idea if a user has probably moved in approximately the pattern you want to detect but it's difficult to know if that would be of any use without an idea of what you are really trying to detect or measure here.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information about your problem. Will your users be doing this walking at your location(s)? If so, you could place an iBeacon at each corner of your (5mx10m) rectangular box, monitor those iBeacons, and detect that the user has entered the immediate proximity of the beacons in clockwise or counter-clockwise order. (Say this is a gym with a walking track.) If you need this to operate anywhere then you may be out of luck, as since you say the GPS is not very accurate for small distances, and gets worse indoors where the GPS signal gets weaker/blocked.

Comment: Alternately, you could use the accelerometer to implement a pedometer application. You'd get the user to measure their average stride length, and use the accelerometer to detect the subtle bouncing motion of each step the user takes. That's probably your best bet, now that I think of it.

Comment: Thanks guys, what about any GPS augmentation things can they be used?